# Subprocess does not execute exiftool command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, exiftool

Iam trying to execute an exif command using subprocess. The command is :

```
['exiftool', '-ID3:Picture', '-b', '-ThumbnailImage', '/home/mediaworker/Downloads/Raabta.mp3', '>', '/mnt/share_PROXY/exifData/Raabta.jpg']
```

Now, the issue is that it returns the status code as 1. But if i execute the same command in the terminal, it executes successfully. The file is written to the location. Is my command going wrong in subprocess ? The error i get when i run my python script is :

```
Error: File not found - >
Error: File not found - /mnt/share_PROXY/exifData/Raabta.jpg
```

The code implementation is as follows:

```
file_name = os.path.basename(file_loc)
file_name = file_name.replace(os.path.splitext(file_name)[1], ".jpg")
dst_loc = os.path.join(dst_loc, file_name)
cmd_ = ["exiftool", "-ID3:Picture", "-b", "-ThumbnailImage", file_loc, ">", dst_loc]
logger.info("Command is {}".format(cmd_))
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            logger.error("Failed to write thumbnail artwork")
        else:                          
            id3_metadata.append({"file_thumbnail_info_path": dst_loc})
    except Exception:
        logger.error("[extract_iptc_metadata] Exception : '{}'".format(ex))
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer with a extract of the code you're running.

Comment: @Sr.S I have added the code for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output refers to the redirection **>**.

The proper way to redirect using subprocess is using the **stdout** parameter.

```py
    with open(dst_loc, 'wb') as f:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_, stdout=f)
        p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'>', '/mnt/share_PROXY/exifData/Raabta.jpg'` part of your command is shell redirection and is a function of the command line/shell.  It is not available when you execute a command from python in this way.

The option you want to look at is the [`-W` (`-tagOut`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#W-FMT--tagOut). [This](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#exiftool--a--b--W-d-f_-t--c.-s--preview:all-dir) would be the example command you want to work off of.  Just replace `-preview:all` with the tag you want to extract, which would be `-ThumbnailImage` in this case.